# Loop through data, store as array in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

This is a very beginner question, but I've searched and can't find anything. I'm attempting to loop through an object, then store the information in an array (or object?) so that I can spit out a string of the items.

```
<% @da = [] %>
<% @report.data_items.each do |di| %>
      <% if di.status == "Complete" %>
        <% @da += di.url_metric.da %> #not sure how to append to the end of the array
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Help? Should I use an array or object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you're doing this in ERB template for some reason. Don't. Keep templates clear and simple. Do this kind of calculations in controller.

Here's a better version:

```
@da = @report.data_items.select {|di| di.status == 'Complete'}.
                         map{|di| di.url_metric.da }
```

Comment: Awesome! Works. Can you explain it a little? What's map do?

Comment: [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) - in short, it transforms elements of your array into other elements, depending on logic in a block you pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
@da = @report.data_items.collect{|di| di.url_metric.da if di.status == "Complete"}.compact
```

Comment: Nah, it will leave nils all over.

Answer (score -1):

Here's shorted varian of what you're trying to accomplish:

```
@da = @report.data_items.select do |item|
  item.status == "Complete"
end.map { |item| item.url_metric.da }.join(", ")
```

Comment: Hmm, when I loop through it to spit out the results I get:

#<DataItem:0x007fb0050b1618>
#<DataItem:0x007fb0050b8aa8>
#<DataItem:0x007fb0050b8030>
#<DataItem:0x007fb0050b7590>

Comment: Why the stringifying join?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, the author says: "...so that I can spit out a string of the items.". Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, missed that. But how do you know the format? Maybe he wants a table row? :)

Comment: Well, after he sees the result, he'll probably understand that he would like to switch from commas to something more appropriate :)